# populate dynamic treeview primefaces

Tags: primefaces, treeview

I'm just starting to handle with spring + hibernate primefaces
and I would like to know how to populate a dynamic treeview. can anyone give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ethemsulan.com/2011/03/dynamic-treeview-recursively-jsf-primefacescreate-dynamic-category-java.html, find a working example here, but in Turkish, native language of author of Primefaces